# Parsing a unique string?

Tags: python, arrays, string, parsing

I'm pretty new to python but I need some help parsing a string with a unique structure. I have a CSV file with a column with the following structure:

```
[Chakroff, Alek; Young, Liane] Boston Coll, Chestnut Hill, MA 02167 USA; [Russell, Pascale Sophie] Univ Surrey, Guildford, Surrey, England; [Piazza, Jared] Univ Lancaster, Lancaster, England
```

I want to just pull the country name present right before the semicolons. So for the above, I want "USA, England, England". The overall structure of the string is:

```
[last name, first name], university, address, zip code, country;
```

How do I get just the countries with this string layout? Is there a way to specify that I want the country name which right before the semicolon? Or maybe an even easier way to pull the information I need?

Please go easy on me, I'm not the best programmer by any means :)

Comment: What does this part mean?  Alek; Young

Comment: So this is one long unique string I have. So in the brackets are names of people arranged last name and first name. Then outside of the brackets I have the University name, the address of the university, a zip code and the country. Then there is a semicolon and then another bracket of names, etc. It follows the same format. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the unique substring before the elements you want:

```
# split string on substring '; ['
for i in s.split('; ['):
    # split each resulting string on space char, return last element of array
    print(i.split()[-1])

USA
England
England
```

Comment: This is incredible, thank you so much for answering, I will try it out!

Comment: what about in the case where the string of interest does not end in a semicolon. I am trying to understand how the for loop you wrote returns the last "England"

Comment: @eruiz: the last segment returned by `split` is the part after the last delimiter, which ends in `England`. (If the string had ended with `;`, you would have gotten `England;`, so watch out for empty fields at the end.) The real problem with this solution is what happens when the country is something like `New Zealand`. But I don't see how you can solve that without knowing the possible countries, because there is no useful delimiter before the country name.

Comment: @rici any idea how to do this with a dataframe of strings following this format? It works for one string that I call s but I have a whole column of strings with 2663 rows. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split() method for strings

```
states = [person_record.split(",")[-1] for person_record in records.split("; [")]
```

Where records is the string you get from your input.

Comment: This doesn't work because the semicolon denotes multiple people in a group in addition to delimiting the elements of interest.

Comment: Correct, I did not notice the additional semicolon, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression:

```
import regex as re

data = "[Chakroff, Alek; Young, Liane] Boston Coll, Chestnut Hill, MA 02167 USA; [Russell, Pascale Sophie] Univ Surrey, Guildford, Surrey, England; [Piazza, Jared] Univ Lancaster, Lancaster, England"
outer_pattern = re.compile(r'\[[^][]+\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|;')
inner_pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s*$')

countries = [country.group(1)
             for chunk in outer_pattern.split(data)
             for country in [inner_pattern.search(chunk)]
             if country]

print(countries)
# ['USA', 'England', 'England']
```

Comment: it does not let me import regex? I keep getting a version error or something of the sort. Does anyone know the problem?